# Cloudfront CORS blocking fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, passenger, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

All the assets except for the fonts load nicely,
and whenever I go to my site I keep getting messages like this one:

> Access to Font at
>   'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff2'
>   from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

As you can see CURL command indicates that no headers are present.

```
curl -H "Origin: https://example.com" -I https://xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 77160
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Rack-Cache: stale, valid, store
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 08:01:26 GMT
X-Content-Digest: d6f48cba7d076fb6f2fd6ba993a75b9dc1ecbf0c
ETag: "2adefcbc041e7d18fcf2d417879dc5a09997aa64d675b7a3c4b6ce33da13f3fe"
X-Runtime: 0.366713
X-Request-Id: 87c9d883-e443-4756-86f9-66b40ed573f6
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger Enterprise 5.1.2
Server: nginx/1.10.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.1.2
Via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 f0eecbf6390179377707b707ebaa1e8b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
Age: 86645
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: FNjQGvROcAdqT6u6PaN3OgEE34mnSsixHNm6WqzWq2boWWYYzVmZPw==
```

Here's AWS Origin configuration
[image]

And this is the behaviour that includes the above origin:

[image]

I even included **rack-cors** to the initializers within the project for the purpose but with no luck.

```
if defined? Rack::Cors
  Rails.configuration.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '/assets/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options, :head], max_age: 0
    end
  end
end
```

Why is this so and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *As you can see CURL command indicates that no headers are present.*  As you can *also* see from the headers, this request didn't pass through CloudFront at all, because the `X-Amz-Cf-Id: ...`, `Via: ...cloudfront.net` and `X-Cache: ... from cloudfront` headers are all missing, and none of those headers can be disabled.  CloudFront is not a contributing factor in this issue, at this point.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I updated the post. Now I have those headers. What can I do next?

Comment: it looks like you sort of fixed the wrong thing, there.  CloudFront wasn't in the loop, so the point of my comment was that you were not having a CloudFront issue -- the problem is somewhere else: your app isn't returning the necessary CORS response headers.  Bringing CloudFront into the loop is complicating your troubleshooting, because now you can't see the impact of changes to your app -- this response, based on the `Age:` header, is 24 hours old.  Disable caching and run a cache invalidation on `*`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Passenger Glyphicon CORS Cloudfront NGINX Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566489/rails-passenger-glyphicon-cors-cloudfront-nginx-issue)

Comment: Any luck @BillyLogan? I am having the same issue...

Answer (score 7):

As of version 5.0, [Rails allows for setting custom HTTP Headers for assets](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/31/rails-5-allows-setting-custom-http-headers-for-assets.html) and you don't have to add dependencies like the `font_assets` gem. In order to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your font, just add the following codde to `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
}
```

**Update on 07/25/2018**:

The header value could also be a specific domain, like the following:

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'https://www.example.org'
}
```

Comment: can 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' be used with specific domains rather than all (*)? ie 'mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com'

Answer (score 2):

I think most common solution is to use `font_assets` gem. Configuration is pretty straightforward. In `config/environments/production.rb` add this

```
config.font_assets = "http://YOUR_ASSET_HOST"
```

Unfortunately I cannot explain this in more details, but that's what we use in our project and it works fine.

Comment: Is it compatible with Rails 5?

Comment: Don't know. The readme says it is for Rails 3.1, but it works also with Rails 4.2, so you can give it a shot.